# PHP array with element that's a splat reference to array element

Tags: php, arrays

I'd like to be able to store an `$ice_cream` array where its contents includes the splat of a reference to the `$toppings` array as `$toppings` may be updated at some point later in the code. I've accomplished this with loops (see below), but as the data set I'm working with is very large (millions of multi-dimensional, associative arrays), I'm hoping there's a "by reference"-like option I'm overlooking which may avoid the loop.

Ideal functionality:

```
<?php
//define selected toppings
$toppings=[];

//store ice cream preference for each person
$ice_cream=[];

$ice_cream['for_me']=['flavor'=>'strawberry', ...&$toppings];//PHP error, obviously

//or

$ice_cream['for_me']=array_merge(['flavor'=>'strawberry'], &$toppings);//PHP error, obviously


//For the sake of this example, you can have an ice cream too (with the **same** $toppings as me)
$ice_cream['for_you']=['flavor'=>'vanilla', ...&$toppings];//PHP error, obviously


//after many conditions and calculations (not shown in this code), the $toppings are specified
$toppings=['sprinkles'=>TRUE,'whipped_cream'=>TRUE];

print_r($ice_cream);//show results

?>
```

Intended result:

```
[
 'for_me' => ['flavor'=>'strawberry', 'sprinkles'=>TRUE, 'whipped_cream'=>TRUE],
 'for_you' =>['flavor'=>'vanilla', 'sprinkles'=>TRUE, 'whipped_cream'=>TRUE]
]
```

(Note: This is a simplified example of what is needed.  In the real world code, `$toppings` is passed by reference and updated so groups of people get specified `$toppings` and additions which differ from other groups.)

Using PHP's `array_merge()` hasn't been successful because `$toppings` needs to be able to change later in the code such as `$toppings['candy']="m&m's";` and we'd need that to be reflected in all relevant `$ice_cream` rows.

Using the following code "works" but requires another loop of all array rows - avoidance of which is the intention of my question:

```
<?php
    //define selected toppings
    $toppings=[];

    //store ice cream preference for each person
    $ice_cream=[];
    
    $ice_cream['for_me']=['flavor'=>'strawberry', 'toppings'=>&$toppings];//PHP error, obviously

    $ice_cream['for_you']=['flavor'=>'vanilla', 'toppings'=>&$toppings];//PHP error, obviously
    

    //after conditions and calculations, the $toppings can be specified
    $toppings=['sprinkles'=>TRUE,'whipped_cream'=>TRUE];
    
    //I cannot afford another loop!
    foreach($ice_cream as &$info){
        $info=array_merge(['flavor'=>$info['flavor']],$info['toppings']);
    }
    unset($info);

    print_r($ice_cream);//this gives desired results

    ?>
```

I've also considered creating objects for each row in $ice_cream (or would there be a benefit to creating an object for `$toppings`, as I believe objects are passed by reference in PHP?  But still would need to "splat" the object somehow or I couldn't see an advantage.

**Edit (to sharpen the scope of this question):**

In PHP, how can I merge an array with the unpacked reference to another array so I can update the referenced array and have it reflected in merged array as shown in the "Ideal functionality" code block above?

Comment: You should objects for this. Variables that "hold objects" are always references.

Comment: The question is not very clear, but claiming you're working with "millions of multi-dimensional, associative arrays" is a big red flag pointing to an XY problem. Why are you not working with a relational database?

Comment: Your problem is not well stated. What is the actual issue you're facing? Using too much memory? Too much space? Too much time? I am also confused about why you'd need/want to put every single user's record into one huge array at the same time. What is your goal?

Comment: @Gabriel, that may be the way I end up going.  But I'm concerned about the cost (memory, speed, etc).

Comment: And what is wrong with the `toppings` array index?  Makes it easier and more structured.

Comment: @miken32, the $ice_cream array takes raw data from the database, performs calculations, and then sends the array to be filtered against a variable array map according to user input.  The number of elements in each $ice_cream row fluctuates based on user input.  So the format doesn't lend itself well to databases - even to temporary tables.

Comment: Just in case you want to play with objects - http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/de7ffa259c9c91ab02facd3fe7170de57af69e0e

Comment: @Alex Howansky, Yes, memory, space, and time are the factors.  Let's say 'cost' is based on the flavor and topping and the cost calulation is appended to each row in $ice_cream. 
 The simplified goal (for this example) is to be able to filter the $ice_cream array to just rows which have a cost between certain limits.  The real world filter tests each row against nested, user-defined defined critera - for example, (cost<$2 AND ( flavor='strawberry' OR 'whipped_cream'=TRUE))

Comment: This question is starting to get way too broad especially if you're now asking about how to filter a result set based on calculated fields and other properties. I suggest you go back to the drawing board and come up with a scalable solution. Working with millions of arrays in memory is not scalable.

Comment: And for the record, you can totally use a database for this. One approach would be to store the users' ice cream configurations in a table. You'd also want to store the price(s) of the configuration. Then, based on the search filters, you read out the configurations that match. `WHERE toppings IN ('sprinkles', 'peanuts') AND flavour = 'strawberry' AND price <= 5.50`

Comment: @AbraCadaver The $toppings array has variable number of elements with variable keys, it would be better if the array was one-dimensional to help with the performance of the filter the array gets passed through.  A multidimensional array would either need to be flattened or the filter function would have to test user-defined map against each $ice_cream_row[$key] AND $ice_cream_row['topping'][$key] (something like $val=($ice_cream_row[$key]??$ice_cream_row['topping'][$key]);) which may be an option, thanks!

Comment: @waterloomatt The conditions are variable.  So, while it may be technically possible to be able to create a temporary table with variable columns and data types, insert millions of rows (including complex calculations), prepare a database query with multiple nested and sanitized user-defined conditions, I respectfully question if a database table is the best approach.  I don't have reputation to take this discussion to a chat, but please know I'm not blindly dismissing your idea.

Comment: As a thought experiment, imagine that the array_merge _did_ work. What would happen if you later wrote `$toppings['flavor'] = 'blood';` Would everyone end up with blood ice cream? Or what if you set `$ice_cream['for_me']['whipped_cream'] = false;'` Would that take precedence over the value in $toppings? Would it matter which order you set them in? How would PHP keep track of the different combinations? References are confusing enough as it is; an array which magically injects any number of values into another array would be a nightmare.

Comment: While you might be right that a _relational_ database isn't the right tool for the job, a database of _some_ sort is definitely what you want here; indeed, you're effectively _building_ a database, but in a language really not built for that job. Take the requirements _right_ back to basics: do you really need to recreate all the data every time (as implied by "create a temporary table ... insert millions of rows")? There are tools like ElasticSearch which are built for exactly this kind of task, and document-based databases like MongoDB and Cassandra would probably be applicable as well.

Comment: @IMSoP I appreciate your experiment and take your point.  As another experiment, consider a warehouse with rows of shelves, each shelf contains many boxes, each box contains bottles of water.  Let's say some of those bottles break after stacking, losing only SOME water. Now if we need to find all shelves containing boxes with blue lining that still contain more than X llitres of water, wouldn't it be nice not to have to open each box and inspect each bottle?  Instead, "reference" the volume of water in each bottle, so changes would update the calculations for each box, shelf, and row - magic!

Comment: @phprox Apart from the magic physics, that sounds like **exactly** what relational databases, and data normalisation, were invented for: each piece of data is stored only in one place, and queries can combine multiple pieces of data on the fly rather than needing to know in advance what redundant values to update. In SQL: `SELECT B.stored_on_shelf_id, B.box_id FROM boxes as B JOIN water_bottles as WB ON WB.stored_in_box_id = B.box_id WHERE B.lining_colour = 'blue' GROUP BY B.stored_on_shelf_id, B.box_id HAVING SUM(WB.remaining_content) > 10` This really isn't a wheel you want to reinvent.

Comment: @IMSoP I appreciate the simplicity of my example lends itself to relational databases.  The real-world problem I was looking to solve - albeit, seemingly a niche concept - is for a user-defined, complex filter on values calculated from database rows.  While queries could technically be written, they would need to selectively compile, perform several calculations on amalgomated values, and filter (with nested AND/OR filters) millions of child+ancestor rows (3M of them in our smallest database).  Performance is a concern, especially when the user controls the filter.

Comment: @phprox It's not that it's "a niche concept", it's that it's a *very complex* one. People have spent **entire careers** finding ways to write **extremely powerful** database and data processing technologies, with all sorts of tricks to do filtering and calculation with very high performance. You are going to get much, much better results by selecting and using one of those tools than you are by writing one yourself. If you really, really want to invent your own database system, PHP is not a good choice of language, because you will never be able to achieve the necessary performance.

Comment: @IMSoP Thank you for your constructive feedback.  I certainly don't want to invent my own database - I've plenty to do!  I'm 15 years in on this PHP+MySQL project and, while going back to basics may help with this particular feature, everything else is working extremely well and I'd prefer not to disrupt (nor re-develop) the core functionality.  I'm intrigued by ElasticSearch and will look into it more.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer appears to be:** "array_merge by reference" isn't available as of PHP 8.0.6

**For Completeness:**
I was looking for a way to produce a one-dimensional array which would include "constant" elements merged with elements from a referenced array; The intent was that the changes to the referenced array would update the one-dimensional array so I could avoid recursion or additional loops.